# Is it possible to find out what theme a specific web site is using?

Tags: themes

I just want to know is there a way to find out (by inspecting links or etc.) to find out what theme a specific web site is using?

P.s. I do not own the sites that I want to check.

Regards,

Comment: If they have a contact form: Ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably view source and find out where the main stylesheet is located. Most likely it will look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" 
href="http://sitename.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/style.css" />
```

Where theme-name is the name you are probably looking for. Cheers.